# How write Rspec test cases in ruby for Faye websocket

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I want write Rspec for this code. Plz help me.

```
    def run_server(credentials, token)
           wskey = get_websocket_key(token)

        EM.run do
          ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new('url'+wskey)
          puts "ws.comm_inactivity_timeout"

          ws.on :open do
            puts "Connected"
          end
    end
```

Comment: Did you try googling 'faye websocket rspec' and clicking on the first link?

Comment: https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby/issues/62